# Scroll effect only once

Tags: javascript, css

I gave images and texts scrolling effects like fade in, but when I scroll, the effect is executed, but when I scroll to the same images, it is delayed. Is it done with Javascript or even CSS which can only be applied once? Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Add some code?

Comment: I designed a homepage and gave posts and photos scrolling effects. You assume you are scrolling from top to bottom and the effects work properly, but when I scroll from bottom to top the posts and Photos are delayed but I only want to run them once

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To run the animation once use the [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property

```css
image, .text {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I do not know why my problem was not solved

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I am currently using WordPress which is one of its features